# php passing variable into array

Tags: php, forms

I'm using a form to pass values into a variable which then I try to use the variable in the array and it doesn't work so I test by doing the following

My Code

```
$Valueid = $_POST['Valueid'];

If I echo $Valueid it contains 64729053b6c57,8800e76767315,9cf2762673352

$storevalues = " $Valueid ";
$replace0 =  str_replace(",", "','", $storevalues);  
$replace1  =  str_replace(" ", "'", $replace0); 

echoing $replace1 = '64729053b6c57','8800e76767315','9cf2762673352'

$a = array($replace1);

print_r ($a);
```

When I have the following

```
$a = array('64729053b6c57','8800e76767315','9cf2762673352');

print_r ($a);
```

I get the following output

```
Array ( [0] => 64729053b6c57 [1] => 8800e76767315 [2] => 9cf2762673352 )
```

If I use

```
$replace1  =  '64729053b6c57','8800e76767315','9cf2762673352'

$a = array($replace1);

print_r ($a);

Array ( [0] => '64729053b6c57','8800e76767315','9cf2762673352' )
```

What I'm trying to solve for is the following

```
$replace1  =  '64729053b6c57','8800e76767315','9cf2762673352'

$a = array($replace1);

print_r ($a);
```

get the following output

```
Array ( [0] => 64729053b6c57 [1] => 8800e76767315 [2] => 9cf2762673352 )
```

Comment: what is your problem and what you want?

Comment: `$replace1  =  '64729053b6c57','8800e76767315','9cf2762673352'` isn't valid syntax for a bunch of different reasons. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you explain further?

Comment: right  understand it's not a valid syntax I was just stating what values are in the $replace1 variable.  when I use the variable in array I need the output to Array ( [0] => 64729053b6c57 [1] => 8800e76767315 [2] => 9cf2762673352 )

Comment: You set $a to an array properly... Why not the same with $replace1?

Comment: Variables are not like copy and pasting code. If you do `$b = array($a)`, then `$b` is an array which contains **one item**, the content of `$a`. Just because the content of `$a` may look like something which may look like three separate items doesn't make it so.

Comment: how can I solve the problem to make it look like 3 separate items

Comment: First show us actual code which actually demonstrates the actual contents of your variable; and/or where that content comes from. What you're currently showing us is impossible, so entirely up to interpretation.

Comment: I added my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use explode method
`$a = explode(",",$_POST['Valueid']);`

Comment: What? This is neither conceptually nor syntactically valid.

Comment: $replace1 = '64729053b6c57,8800e76767315,9cf2762673352';

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can do

```
$replace[0] = 'this1';
$replace[1] = 'this2';
$replace[2] = 'this3';
$a= $replace;

print_r($a);
```

here you will get the result of :

```
Array ( [0] => this1 [1] => this2 [2] => this3 )
```